# Grunt is too slow in mobile and webviews

Tags: javascript, webview, gruntjs, gulp, webpack

I'm currently using grunt as javascript task runner for a single page application. We have webviews pointing from our app and as grunt minifies and make all the js to one file and css to one file, whenever we start loading webview the entire js and css file is downloaded which I think is the rootcause for the app being too slow.

I heard about gulp and webpack as alternatives but not sure whether they will serve the above mentioned purpose better than grunt or not.

Can anyone suggest any other alternative task runner for the above mentioned purpose ?

Please correct me if I'm wrong in anything mentioned above.

Comment: on which framework/library your app built?

Comment: How big of a file are we talking?  I use `grunt serve` to work on enterprise level applications without any problems

Comment: My scripts file is about 2MB. The issue is mainly on webviews it downloads entire 2MB which in 2G/3G takes too much time to load.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your thinking is correct. Loading a large file (bundle of many js/css files) at initial time may lead the user to wait for some time to get the page loaded. But once the files are loaded you never feel a delay.

If you think that loading takes time, you want to avoid loading the huge bundle at initial page load, you could go with `lazy / on-demand` loading of files.

yes, whatever you heard about gulp + webpack is right. The best solution for your problem is to use [`code-splitting`](https://webpack.github.io/docs/code-splitting.html) feature of webpack which will split your app into multiple bundles and load them when they are required.

There are nice examples [here](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/tree/master/examples) for webpack

### Update

You can achieve lazy loading without using webpack as well. Please refer the [link](https://oclazyload.readme.io/docs/external-help-articles-tutorials-videos) which has list of git repos and articles explaining the lazy loading options.

Comment: Thanks Jagan . I'm using angularJs. The main focus is webviews in an app. Suppose I want xyz.com/a then it will download entire script file which takes so much time in 2G/3G.

Comment: 1.5.6. Will do some research on code splitting using webpack. Btw what you will personally suggest as a long term solution. Because we have more traffic on app and as webviews are loading too slowly we are facing many issues :(

Comment: Go with link which i provided with the update section. It has example for webpack as well